# Error when compiling the driver for MYSQL for QT

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to build the `MYSQL` driver for QT so I can include it in my projects. I am using `QT 5.5.1`, `MYSQL 5.7`, and `MinGW 4.9.2 32 bit`. I open the ".pro" file from the driver source code in the `QT Creator` and add `INCLUDEPATH += C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/include` and 
`QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/lib/libmysql.lib` to the project file and attempt to build. I get one error in response.

This is the error:

> error: mysql.append(\lib\libmysql.lib): No such file or directory

This is the compiler output:

> g++ -Wl,-s -shared -Wl,-subsystem,windows
>   -Wl,--out-implib,C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlmysql.a
>   -o ........\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll .obj/release/main.o .obj/release/qsql_mysql.o .obj/release/moc_qsql_mysql_p.o 
>   -LC:\Program -LFiles -L(x86)\MySQL\MySQL -LServer -L5.7\lib\libmysql.lib mysql.append(\lib\libmysql.lib) -Ls:/lib -LC:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/lib -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core .obj\release\qsqlmysql_resource_res.o  g++: error:
>   mysql.append(\lib\libmysql.lib): No such file or directory
>   Makefile.Release:81: recipe for target
>   '........\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll' failed mingw32-make[1]:
>   *** [........\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll] Error 1 mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory
>   'C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql' mingw32-make: ***
>   [release-all] Error 2 makefile:38: recipe for target 'release-all'
>   failed 11:55:06: The process
>   "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project mysql (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1
>   MinGW 32bit) When executing step "Make"

What can I do to stop this error?

Comment: I don't think the directory `QMAKE_LIBDIR` should be a file path.

Comment: @tadman Well if I'm adding a lib file to the Qmake lib wouldn't it need to be a file path? I've also seen many examples on sites where it is used like this without any problems. I have tried so many different approaches to building the driver with all kinds of errors that seem to be from the system more so than from my approach at building it.

Comment: It says `DIR` in the name. Try specifying a directory, not a file. Usually `PATH` means file.

Comment: @tadman I see your point now. How then can I reference the file for a successful build? I'm new enough at this that I rarely know how to do things on my own with out references or guidance on it.